# How get XML response from ImageShack API?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, imageshack

i'm using ImageShack API and this is my code:

```
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://www.imageshack.us/upload_api.php?">

        <p><input type="file" name="fileupload"></p>
        <p>Tags:<input type="text" name="tags" value=""></p>
        <p><input type="text" name="key" value="xxxx"></p>
        <p><select name="optsize">
                <option value="320x240">Small (320x240)</option>
                <option value="426x320" selected>Medium (426x320)</option>
                <option value="640x480">Big (640x480)</option>
            </select></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Go"></p>
    </form>
```

It works fine, but when i click 'Go' appears in my web browser the whole file XML that came as response, i need get this response in my servlet or JSP.

How do i get this XML response ?

Best regards,
Valter Henrique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the mutlipart post request from your servlet.

HttpClient would enable you to do this. That's fairly involved but I think this is a good example of how to do it.

http://evgenyg.wordpress.com/2010/05/01/uploading-files-multipart-post-apache/